# Fastest way to identify area from 2D coordinates

Tags: python, if-statement, coordinates

I have the following code:

```
def findRegion(lat,lon):
    '''Gets a lat between -90,90 and a lon between -180,180 and returns a character'''
    if lat >= 50:
        y='ABCD'
    elif lat >= 0:
        y='EFGH'
    elif lat <= -50:
        y='MNOP'
    else:
        y='IJKL'

    if lon <= -90:
        x='AEIM'
    elif lon <= 0:
        x='BFJN'
    elif lon <= 90:
        x='CGKO'
    else:
        x='DHLP'

    for c in y:
        if c in x:
            return c
```

This function gets two coordinates and returns one of the 16 sector codes shown [here](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/topo/gltiles.html). The code works perfectly, but it will get called lots of times, so I'm looking for the fastest possible solution. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: How slow is this ? Did you profile it ? Look into premature optimization.

Comment: @EricFortin: googling after premature optimization, I think it is exactly what I'm doing...

Comment: Did you get the end of the quote: ... is the root of all evil.

Comment: @EricFortin ok, thanks for setting me on the right path :) I go back to work, and see the answers here when I realize how slow this function actually is (or is not) compared to other parts of my code. Do I get the message? :)

Comment: Yes, although you could still do a change in your implementation that might help with speed but much more with readability: Build a list of list to store those Region and try to index them directly instead of looping and matching letter.

Comment: See my answer related to my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would improve the speed a little bit by skipping the double for(which is really marginal since there is only 4 iterations per loop so a worst case of 16 character comparisons) at the end of the function. Although, I would think the major improvement is in the readability which is often more important.

```
def findRegion(lat, lon):
    regions = ( ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'), ('E', 'F', 'G', 'H'), ('I', 'J', 'K', 'L'), ('M', 'N', 'O', 'P'))

    lat_index = 0;
    if lat >= 50:
        lat_index = 0
    elif lat >= 0:
        lat_index = 1
    elif lat <= -50:
        lat_index = 2
    else:
        lat_index = 3

    lon_index = 0
    if lon <= -90:
        lon_index = 0
    elif lon <= 0:
        lon_index = 1
    elif lon_index <= 90:
        lon_index = 2
    else:
        lon_index = 3

    return regions[lat_index][lon_index]

print findRegion(-45, 50)
```

Answer (score 3):

This should speed the process by using the x and y to find the region in a one dimensional string. May actually be slower due to the use of clamp.

```
clamp = lambda n, minimum, maximum: max(min(maximum, n), minimum)

def a(lat, lon):
    ## get lat, lon sections
    sec_lat = clamp((lat+90)/45,0,3)
    sec_lon = clamp((lon+180)/90,0,3)

    ## convert two values into a 1 dimensional list value
    sec = sec_lat*4 + sec_lon

    return "MNOPIJKLEFGHABCD"[sec]
```

Comment: +1 Just a suggestion, though: You could write that a bit more efficiently as `sec_lat = int((lat + 90) / 45)`, etc as long as you can safely assume that the `lat`, `lon` values are within range.

Comment: Slightly more readable if you reverse the longitude with sec_lat = (180 - (lat + 90)) so you don't have to use an esoteric string arrangement

Comment: @JoeKington - that was my first try, but I ran into some issues with 360/90 = 4 (outside of the list). If you can improve it with an edit I will gladly accept it.